# Understanding the RSI Formula - $RSI = {\color {red}{100} - { \color {red}{100} \over {\color {red} 1} + {n_{up} \over n_{down}} }}$

Tags: statistics

RSI (Relative Strength Index) is an Oscillator Formula used in trading to detect overbought/oversold conditions. High values suggests overbought and low values suggest oversold conditions in the market.

While I understand what the denominator shown in the formula below does, I am having trouble understanding what the values highlighted in red does to the overall picture from a mathematical standpoint.

$$RSI = {\color {red}{100} -  { \color {red}{100} \over {\color {red} 1} + {n_{up} \over n_{down}}  }}$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I dont honestly know. Im not an accountant or a finance person. Just getting into the subjects myself.  I suspect what they are doing here - and this seems to be common practice - is to algebraically manipulate a perfectly reasonable ratio (in black, which you understand), into a sort of sliding scale between 0 and 100, to sort of pass off as a percentage. Is it mathematically rigorous? Probably not, but finances isnt about objective truth so much as it is about standardization of metrics that can be easily compared.

Comment: Its obvious from the equation that when $n_{up}$ is 0, or negligible compared to $n_{down}$, then the RSI = 0%. When its reversed, the RSI = 100%. When the two are perfectly balanced, RSI = 50%.  This is by design.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Thanks You are right, I was intending to understanding the parts from a mathematical perspective. What does the additional 1 do and having a 100 numerator in this case do ?

Comment: I recommend playing around with it to find out.  It all has to do with getting the RSI numbers 0 to 100 to line up where you want them.  The 100 is the numerator scales it to appear like a percentage.  Its subtracted from the constant 100 because they wanted it to go from 100 to 0, rather than from 0 to 100.  The 1 in the denominator is just a mathematical necessity.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Thank You. Would this be under Polynomials ? What would be a good book for further reading ?

Comment: I cant really recommend a book. Im not that well studied on financial subjects.

Answer (score 1):

This is the percentage of moves which have been up rather than down.

The proportion up rather than down is clearly $\dfrac{n_{up}}{n_{up}+n_{down}}$ and gives something between $0$ and $1$.  Multiply it by $100$ if you want a percentage between $0$ and $100$ so $100\dfrac{n_{up}}{n_{up}+n_{down}}$.

The rest is manipulation: $$100\dfrac{n_{up}}{n_{up}+n_{down}} = 100-100\dfrac{n_{down}}{n_{down}+n_{up}} = 100-100\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{n_{up}}{n_{down}}}$$ though it is not obvious why anyone would do this.  Perhaps because technical analysis is little more than astrology.

Comment: Thank You Henry. The Formula provided seems to be the industry norm, though i share the same sentiments, seems unnecessary. It seems it's harder to visualize when the manipulated formula is used. How would one visualize it without manipulation ?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Henry 's answer. The idea behind using this notation for $\textbf{Relative Strength Index}$ rather than simply $$100*\frac{n_{up}}{n_{up}+n_{down}}$$
is because

> The RSI is classified as a momentum oscillator, measuring the velocity and magnitude of price movements. Momentum is the rate of the rise or fall in price. The RSI computes momentum as the ratio of higher closes to lower closes

In finance, momentum is generally termed as $\textbf{Relative Strength}$.

> The ratio of these averages is the relative strength or relative strength factor:

$$RS={\frac{{\text{SMMA}}(U,n)}{{\text{SMMA}(D,n)}}}$$

then,

> The relative strength factor is then converted to a relative strength index between 0 and 100:

$$RSI=100-{100 \over {1+RS}}$$

### The rationale is basically to have RSI in terms of RS.

Please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_strength_index.